# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 Causing IDE To Hang

Tags: visual-studio-2015

After having Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 installed the IDE hangs and won't start at the splash screen, the only fix is to run devenv /setup. or to do a repair looks like it is like the known issue which was not updating the cache, however this is for the prerelase update.

I checked my logs and I get:

548

```
<type>Error</type>
<source>Extension Manager</source>
<description>Error loading extension: This VSIX does not apply to any product installed on this machine. The problem could be that the VSIX manifest&apos;s format is not recognized, or that the manifest has been corrupted. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. </description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\VSGRAPHICS\</path>
```

Also checking the manifest file it proves its empty.

Any ideas on how to fix it? knowing that when VS starts in safe mode it works just fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this same error after installing Update 2. For me it turned out to be one of my extensions (Automatic Versions). After removing it my Visual Studio went back to normal. You can try removing your extensions one at a time in safe mode to find the culprit.

Comment: Had the same problem and was caused by the same extension. Removed it and everything seems to be working again! Thanks

Comment: Same here! I could launch one instance or two instances, and then it would hang. Removing Automatic Versions fixed the issue

Comment: Brilliant! removing Automatic Version fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: We've isolated the conflict with Automatic Versions and VS2015 Update 2 and should have a fix out by 4/29.

Comment: The fix for this has been posted, please update Automatic Versions to >= 1.5