# Visual Studio 2015 update 2 Keeps Restarting at some point

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crash-reports

So when I'm opening a project Visual Studio Restart at some point. Some times it's restart after i open a project. sometimes when i publish a project or while coding.

so i tried to open Visual Studio with Log parameter and this is the error that i got.

```
   <entry>
    <record>293</record>
    <time>2017/12/06 08:38:15.363</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Error loading extension: This VSIX does not apply to any product installed on this machine. The problem could be that the VSIX manifest&apos;s format is not recognized, or that the manifest has been corrupted. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. </description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\VSGRAPHICS\</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>294</record>
    <time>2017/12/06 08:38:15.477</time>
    <type>Error</type>  
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Error loading extension: This VSIX does not apply to any product installed on this machine. The problem could be that the VSIX manifest&apos;s format is not recognized, or that the manifest has been corrupted. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. </description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\VSGRAPHICS\</path>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>295</record>
    <time>2017/12/06 08:38:15.478</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.Extensions&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\N14XF2NN.ESA\...</description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TEAMFOUNDATION\TEAM EXPLORER\</path>
  </entry>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 Causing IDE To Hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399687/visual-studio-2015-update-2-causing-ide-to-hang)

Comment: Removing Automatic Versions should fix the issue.

Comment: Where can i find Automatic Versions? I don't see it in my extensions

Comment: Have a look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399687/visual-studio-2015-update-2-causing-ide-to-hang